# TreeView does not output anything in a window Tkinter Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview, psycopg2

I am new to python and tkinter and I'm trying to make a simple GUI to interact with my database on postgresql

I made a Treeview  inside a function to display a table but it does not

All it does it create a window with nothing on it I tried to create it  with tk.Frame or to create only the Treeview but it still does not show

```
HERE IS THE CODE
```

```
import psycopg2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

root  = tk.Tk()
root.title('DB')
root.geometry('1500x1200')
root.minsize (1600, 1200)
root.maxsize (root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight())



def main():
        conn=paginaLogin()
        




def errore(msg):
        messagebox.showerror('',msg)
               

def paginaLogin():


        def db_login(nomeUtente, passwordUtente):

                conn=None

                try:
                        conn = psycopg2.connect(
                        host = 'localhost',
                        dbname = 'MyDB',
                        user = nomeUtente,
                        password = passwordUtente,
                        port = '5432'
                        )
                        return conn

                except Exception as error:
                        return conn
                

        def vai_menu ():
                if(username.get()!='' and password.get()!=''):

                        if(username.get()==''and password.get()==''):
                                
                                login.destroy()
                                paginaMenu(conn)
                        else:
                                errore('Username o Password errati riprova')

        def vai_menu_fast ():
                login.destroy()
                paginaMenu(conn)
                
        login = tk.Frame(root)

        stringaUtente = tk.Label(login, text='Inserisci il nome utente',font=('Bold',25),bg='light blue')
        stringaUtente.place(x=180,y=100)
        username = tk.Entry (login, font=('Bold',15))
        username.place(x=160,y=150,height=50, width=300)

        stringaPassword = tk.Label(login, text='Inserisci la password',font=('Bold',25),bg='light blue')
        stringaPassword.place(x=200,y=300)
        password = tk.Entry (login, font=('Bold',15),show='*')
        password.place(x=160,y=350,height=50, width=300)

        bottone = tk.Button(login, text='login',font=('Bold',15),bg='blue',fg='black', command=vai_menu_fast)
        bottone.place(x=120,y=550,height=50, width=350)



        login.pack(padx=100,pady=100)
        login.pack_propagate(False)
        login.configure(height=800, width= 600,bg='grey')

        conn= db_login(nomeUtente=username.get(), passwordUtente=password.get())
        return conn

def paginaMenu(conn):
  

        def vai_login ():
                menu.destroy()
                paginaLogin()
        
        def vai_bilanci ():
                menu.destroy()
                paginaBilanci(conn)

        def finestra(conn):

                finestra = tk.Toplevel()
                finestra.geometry('1200x1000')

                colonne = ('Nome', 'Cognome','Codice Fiscale','E-mail','Telefono','Luogo di nascita','Data di nascita','Residenza','CAP','Indirizzo')
                tabella = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=colonne, show='headings')
                stile=ttk.Style(root)
                stile.theme_use('clam')

                

                tabella.column('Nome',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('Cognome',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('Codice Fiscale',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('E-mail',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('Telefono',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('Luogo di nascita',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('Data di nascita',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('Residenza',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('CAP',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.column('Indirizzo',width=50,minwidth=50,anchor=tk.CENTER)

                tabella.heading ('Nome',text='Nome',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('Cognome',text='Cognome',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('Codice Fiscale',text='Codice Fiscale',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('E-mail',text='E-mail',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('Telefono',text='Telefono',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('Luogo di nascita',text='Luogo di nascita',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('Data di nascita',text='Data di nascita',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('Residenza',text='Residenza',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('CAP',text='CAP',anchor=tk.CENTER)
                tabella.heading ('Indirizzo',text='Nome',anchor=tk.CENTER)

                cur = conn.cursor() 
                cur.execute('set search_path to DBFag;')
                cur.execute('SELECT * FROM vistaSoci')
                rows = cur.fetchall()
                count = cur.rowcount

                for i in rows:
                        tabella.insert('', 'end', values=i)
                tabella.pack
                


        menu = tk.Frame(root)

        ##      menù principale      ##
        bottone = tk.Button(menu, text='Vai a login',font=('Bold',15),bg='blue',fg='black', command=vai_login)
        bottone.place(x=0,y=0,height=50, width=1400)


        ##      menù modifica      ##
        stringaUtente = tk.Label(menu, text='Inserisci aggiorna o elimina uno di questi campi',font=('Bold',25),bg='light blue',height=2,width=100)
        stringaUtente.place(x=-40,y=150)

        bottone = tk.Button(menu, text='Soci',font=('Bold',30),bg='blue',fg='black', command=vai_login)
        bottone.place(x=100,y=300,height=50, width=250)

        bottone = tk.Button(menu, text='Tessere',font=('Bold',30),bg='blue',fg='black', command=vai_login)
        bottone.place(x=400,y=300,height=50, width=250)

        bottone = tk.Button(menu, text='Entrate',font=('Bold',30),bg='blue',fg='black', command=vai_login)
        bottone.place(x=700,y=300,height=50, width=250)

        bottone = tk.Button(menu, text='Uscite',font=('Bold',30),bg='blue',fg='black', command=vai_login)
        bottone.place(x=1000,y=300,height=50, width=250)

        ##      menù visita      ##
        stringaUtente = tk.Label(menu, text='Visualizza uno di questi campi',font=('Bold',25),bg='light blue',height=2,width=100)
        stringaUtente.place(x=-40,y=500)

        bottone = tk.Button(menu, text='Bilanci',font=('Bold',50),bg='blue',fg='black', command=vai_bilanci)
        bottone.place(x=250,y=600,height=100, width=950)

        bottone = tk.Button(menu, text='Soci',font=('Bold',30),bg='blue',fg='black', command=lambda:finestra(conn))
        bottone.place(x=200,y=800,height=70, width=450)
        
        bottone = tk.Button(menu, text='Tessere',font=('Bold',30),bg='blue',fg='black', command=vai_login)
        bottone.place(x=800,y=800,height=70, width=450)

        

         

        menu.pack(padx=100,pady=100)
        menu.pack_propagate(False)
        menu.configure(height=1200, width= 1500,bg='grey')


def paginaBilanci(conn):
        cur = conn.cursor()
        def vai_menu ():
                bilanci.destroy()
                paginaMenu(conn)

        bilanci = tk.Frame(root)

        goBack_btn = tk.Button(bilanci, text='X', font=('Bold', 30), bd=0, command=vai_menu)   
        goBack_btn.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.E)

        cur.execute('set search_path to DBFag;')
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Rendiconto')
        val = cur.fetchall()

        stringaRendiconto = tk.Label(bilanci, text=val ,font=('Bold',25),bg='light blue',height=2,width=100)
        stringaRendiconto.place(x=-40,y=500)

        bilanci.pack(padx=100,pady=100)
        bilanci.pack_propagate(False)
        bilanci.configure(height=1200, width= 1500,bg='grey')


main()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code

1. is that u have forgotten to call the `pack` method on the Treeview widget. U should add the parentheses.
2. u are passing `root` as the parent of the `ttk.Treeview` instead of `finestra`. So, the Treeview should be a child of `finestra`, which is the Toplevel window you created.

Changes:

```
def finestra(conn):
    finestra = tk.Toplevel()
    finestra.geometry('1200x1000')

    colonne = ('Nome', 'Cognome','Codice Fiscale','E-mail','Telefono','Luogo di nascita','Data di nascita','Residenza','CAP','Indirizzo')
    tabella = ttk.Treeview(finestra, columns=colonne, show='headings')
    stile=ttk.Style(finestra)
    stile.theme_use('clam')

    # ...

    tabella.pack()
```

Comment: TYSM, I've actually figured out the second error but still was not showing up